# C++ Non binary tree: getting tree leaves collection (performance question)

Tags: c++, tree

I have a nonbinary tree structure build form nodes like that:

```
struct Node
{
    Node*              pa_;
    std::vector<Node*> children_;

    std::vector<Node*> GetLeaves()
};
```

By tree leafs i understand tree nodes without children. Method that provides collection of tree leafs looks like that:

```
    std::vector<Node*> Node::GetLeaves()
    {
        std::vector<Node*> ret;
        if(!children_.size())
        {
            ret.push_back(this);
        }
        else
        {
            for (auto child : children_)
            {
                auto child_leaves = child->GetLeaves()
                ret.insert( ret.end(),
                            child_leaves.begin(),
                            child_leaves.end() );
            }
        }
        return std::move(ret);
    }
```

Lest say that that whole tree can have hundreds of leafs.

Using vector as container for leafs, means lots of memory reallocation when inserting to the returned collection happens.

The Question is: is using std::list instead of std:: vector not preferable?

thx in advance

Comment: As your list only contains pointers I doubt you'll see much benefit using `std::list`. Presumably your implementation is also incorrect as it returns the grand childrend of the current node and doesn't check whether they are leaves?

Comment: const std::vector<Node*>& GetLeaves() {return children_;} ought to be enough and fast. Why do you need anything else? Seems like something is off on the design-side.

Comment: @Alain just corrcted ;)

Comment: Well, you are generating a new vector for each inner node. Pass the result container as a parameter for the function to fill to avoid this. Alternative approach: Implement an iterator that lets the user iterate the leaves using the existing structure without the need to generate lists.

Comment: @Nico Passing return vector as parmeter does not help with repetitive inserting, it would be changed with repetitive push_back. (@Jeffrey  design corrected)

Comment: Of course, it does not avoid the need to put the elements in the vector. But you will do so only once and you will have only a single vector. Currently, you keep the elements multiple times in multiple vectors.

Comment: @Nico Yes I must agree to that :). But in that perspective is using 'list' instead of 'vector' more preferable?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the recursion would eliminate some of the copying and allow you to just build a single list:

```
std::vector<Node*> Node::GetLeaves()
{
    if (children_.empty())
    {
      return std::vector<Node*>(this, 1);
    }
    std::vector<Node*> ret;
    std::stack<Node*> nodes;
    nodes.push(this);
    while (!nodes.empty())
    {
      Node* parent = nodes.top();
      nodes.pop();
      for (auto node : parent->children_)
      {
        if (node->children_.empty())
        {
          ret.push_back(node);
        }
        else
        {
          nodes.push(node);
        }
      }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If you want to change the traversal order you can change the `stack` to a `queue`.

Comment: I can see the idea, but I do not see how this exact code would work. Firstly std::stack does not support range-based loops. Secondly it would push and pop over and over again the same node (push should affect children_ I suppose).

Comment: @BudziwojMan fixed (though still not tested as you didn't provide a [mcve] to test against)